# Converting Ndiff (From Nmap) XML File To Html

Tags: python, html, xml, xslt, nmap

I am building a script to discover changes in ports on my network over night. To do this I wrote those 2 lines:

```
nmap -sS -oX a.xml --stylesheet C:\Nmap\nmap.xsl
ndiff --xml a.xml b.xml
```

What I now want to do, is to convert the output of the `ndiff` command (`b.xml`) to a nice HTML page. I read about `xsltproc` and I used it but it gives me errors all the time (Cannot parse the xml and html files).

Can someone help me?

Comment: If xsltproc can't parse the xml, you should first check if b.xml is valid xml. Won't recommend one, but if you google 'xml validator' you'll get some links where you can just check if your xml is valid.

Comment: @matthias_h Maybe you know a way to parse the xml to xsl?